# Opening locally installed windows program via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I want a button on my website that will open a windows program on the users computer. So for example, someone clicks "Remote Desktop" on my website, and it will open mstsc.exe on the machine.

Is this possible with any language?

Comment: You cannot do this without some sort of browser plugin/extension, otherwise websites could execute any program randomly and do some damage to the users system.

Comment: how is this related to [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery], and to [tag:performance]? You have added those tags, but didn't really explain what part of your problem has to do with JS or jQuery, nor what it has to do with code efficiency ([tag:performance]).

Comment: Any ways you can recommend?

Comment: This is a potential security nightmare. How about letting your browser running `format.exe` which erases your whole hard drive?

Comment: If you have control over the users machine, you can install a custom protocol https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers which can open up whatever.

Comment: @epascarello you should probably post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The way you could do this is via an [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). For that to work though, your application itself needs to have an URI scheme attached to it. Examples include `mailto:` (opens your email client - can also be a web client such as gmail), `irc:` (opens Internet Relay Chat client) and an example of a truly custom URI scheme (it isn't listed in [the official list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)) is Github's Desktop application, which uses the URI scheme `github-windows:`. Again, for this to work, the app itself needs to have this built into itself.

I assume you didn't make this mstsc.exe "Remote Desktop" yourself, it is impossible to start this application in any way whatsoever using just your browser. If that would indeed be possible, it would be a massive security hole. It would mean you could simply run any program (or uninstall file) you'd like.

**Note:** If you did indeed make the application yourself, I suggest asking another question on this site, but making it specifically about registering custom URI schemes to your application, and also specifying what language your application is written in.

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer :)  URI schemes are becoming very popular, I just downloaded the Amazon Kindle Reader, and sure enough they have a custom protocol...similar to Skype and lot of others...